# How to make an image draggable inside Imageview?

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-framelayout

Is this possible, have anyone done anything close to this? I saw this behaviour in an ios app and need to reproduce it, basically the image is full size on the X axis and it can move up and down through the Y axis inside an Imageview, I tried doing this with an Imageview inside a FrameLayout without success, the Image is always cropped to the max size of the Imageview which is relative to its parent (FrameLayout). Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just write your own class. Intercept the touch events, monitor the vertical offset and redraw the image with this vertical offset.

Comment: Good Idea, will be trying that to see how it comes